# Excel VBA: Using DDE to launch and push data to Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, dde

I am working with VBA in Excel 2010.  I need to copy four values from the worksheet, then I'd like to use DDE (in VBA) to:

1. launch Internet Explorer
2. navigate to a intranet URL
3. tab thru the web page, pasting the four values fromt he worksheet into their respective fields (in the web page), and
4. execute the save button at the bottom of the web page.

I can translate my experience with DDE Excel to Bloomberg to solve #3 and I can probably figure out #4.  Can someone help me with sample VBA code statements that solve #1 and #2 above?

Comment: I don't know in which way you will use any DDE solution for step 2 & 3. Could you please add code for these steps to you question after all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for step 1 and 2:

```
Sub Steps_1_2()

'step 1st
    Dim oIE As InternetExplorer
    Set oIE = New InternetExplorer
'step 2nd
    oIE.Visible = True
    'change the address to intranet
    oIE.navigate "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until oIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    MsgBox "IE Ready for step 3 and 4"
End Sub
```